# Django - Last Updated By and Update Date not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Hi I need someone's advice.

I created a form add organizations and a form to edit organizations. These are working fine.

However, I have Last Updated By and Update Date fields on the model - These are not picking up the datetime and user information when editing the organization.

views.py

```
@login_required()
def organization_edit(request, pk):
    org = Organization.objects.get(org_id=pk)
    form = OrganizationEditForm(instance=org)

    # Update Org 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrganizationEditForm(request.POST, instance=org)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.organization_code = form.cleaned_data['organization_code']
            form.company_name = form.cleaned_data['company_name']
            form.legal_name = form.cleaned_data['legal_name']
            form.business_registration_no = form.cleaned_data['business_registration_no']
            form.vat_registration_no = form.cleaned_data['vat_registration_no']
            form.industry_distribution = form.cleaned_data['industry_distribution']
            form.industry_education = form.cleaned_data['industry_education']
            form.industry_healthcare = form.cleaned_data['industry_healthcare']
            form.industry_manufacturing = form.cleaned_data['industry_manufacturing']
            form.industry_retail = form.cleaned_data['industry_retail']
            form.industry_services = form.cleaned_data['industry_services']
            form.effective_start_date = form.cleaned_data['effective_start_date']
            form.effective_end_date = form.cleaned_data['effective_end_date']
            
            org = form.save(commit=False)

            org.last_updated_by = request.user

            org.save()
            return redirect('organizations_settings')

    context = {
        'form':form,
        'org':org,
    }

    return render(request, 'settings/edit_organization.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Organization(models.Model):

    org_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=7, default=org_id_generate, editable=False)
    organization_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    company_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Company Name", max_length=60)
    legal_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Legal Name", max_length=100)
    industry_distribution = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Distribution", default=False)
    industry_education = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Education", default=False)
    industry_healthcare = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Healthcare", default=False)
    industry_manufacturing = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Manufacturing", default=False)
    industry_retail = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Retail", default=False)
    industry_services = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Services", default=False)
    business_registration_no = models.CharField(verbose_name="Business Registration Number", max_length=15, blank=True)
    vat_registration_no = models.CharField(verbose_name="VAT Registration Number", max_length=15, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="Created_By", verbose_name="Created By")
    effective_start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    effective_end_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    last_updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="Last_Updated_By", verbose_name="Last Updated By")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You might have mistaken on how `default` value works in this case.
Your `updated_date`field is kind of working while creating the row for the first time because of the dynamic default value datetime.now(). But it won't be automatically updated automatically later on. For this use I'd advise you to use DateTimeField with `auto_now_add` and `auto_now` set to True respectfully:

```
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield

This way you won't need to update those values manually. 
`Sidenote:` Those values are False by default so you don't need to specify auto_now_add=False.

Sadly I don't see why updating the last_updated_by field is not working properly if the Organization editing is otherwise working as intended. Changing the modified_date to work and trying again could be a good test to see if the Organization instance at hand is actually updated properly.